# How simplify the function with if?

Tags: php, php-7

I have fucntion like this:

```
public function isSuperAdmin() {
    if($this->role->id == '1') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How it maximum simplify?

Comment: What do you mean by "simplify"? Do you want to get rid of the `if`? Do you want to transform it into a one-liner? Keep in mind that this may impact readability and maintainability too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As result of comparison is **already** a boolean value - return it:

```
public function isSuperAdmin() {
    return $this->role->id == '1';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public function isSuperAdmin() {
    return ($this->role->id == '1');
}
```